# Compression time of a spring

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

can someone show me how to deal with this problem? Thank you

A mass $m$ moves on a smooth horizontal plane with constant velocity $v$ directed parallel to the plane. At a certain instant it comes into contact with the free end of a horizontal spring, of elastic constant $K$. Considering the other end of the spring locked to a fixed support, determine:

- The duration of the interaction between the spring and the mass $m$

[image]

Comment: You should ask this question in Physics SE.

Comment: It's a conservation of energy problem. You have kinetic into elastic potential. You calculate net acceleration and use that to find the time it takes to go from $v$ to 0. Then you double the time. The period of the mass on the spring is then $t=2\pi(\frac{m}{k})^{2}$.

Comment: Note that the dimension of $\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}$ is [rad/sec] so $2\pi(\frac{m}{K})^2$ has dimension $\mbox{sec}^4/\mbox{rad}^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in contact with the spring the movement is described by

$$
m\ddot x = -K x \Rightarrow \dot x\ddot x + \frac{K}{m} x\dot x = 0 \Rightarrow \dot x^2 + \frac{K}{m} x^2 = C
$$

Now supposing enough length in the spring, by energy conservation we have

$$
\frac{1}{2}m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} K (\Delta x)^2
$$

with $\Delta x$ the maximum spring recoil.

then

$$
v^2 + \frac{K}{m}0= C\Rightarrow \dot x^2 + \frac{K}{m} x^2 =  \frac{K}{m}(\Delta x)^2
$$

and then

$$
\Delta x\sqrt{ \frac{K}{m} }dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\Delta x}\right)^2}}
$$

hence

$$
\Delta x\sqrt \frac{K}{m}\Delta t = \int_0^{\Delta x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\Delta x}\right)^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\pi\Delta x
$$

and finally

$$
\Delta t = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{ \frac{K}{m}}}
$$

but the total contact time is

$$
2\Delta t = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}}}
$$